# Terraform is unable to apply the ... operator

Tags: terraform

(I use terraform 0.12.20)

I have the following snippet in my code:

```
locals {
    x = merge(values({
        for location in local.locations: location => {
            for apsvc_name in var.apsvc_names: "${location}-${apsvc_name}" => {
                location = location
                apsvc_name = apsvc_name
            }
        }
    })...)
```

The `x` local is then output. Applying the configuration results in:

```
Error: Invalid expanding argument value

  on ..\..\hosting-modules\web\app_hosting.tf line 35, in locals:
  35:     x = merge(values({
  36:         for location in local.locations: location => {
  37:             for apsvc_name in var.apsvc_names: "${location}-${apsvc_name}" => {
  38:                 location = location
  39:                 apsvc_name = apsvc_name
  40:             }
  41:         }
  42:     })...)

The expanding argument (indicated by ...) must be of a tuple, list, or set
type.
```

Now if I strip the call to `merge(...)` and assign the result of `values` to x, the result is output just fine:

```
x = [
  {
    "centralus-backoffice" = {
      "apsvc_name" = "backoffice"
      "location" = "centralus"
    }
    "centralus-gateway" = {
      "apsvc_name" = "gateway"
      "location" = "centralus"
    }
    "centralus-javascriptclient" = {
      "apsvc_name" = "javascriptclient"
      "location" = "centralus"
    }
  },
  {
    "eastus2-backoffice" = {
      "apsvc_name" = "backoffice"
      "location" = "eastus2"
    }
    "eastus2-gateway" = {
      "apsvc_name" = "gateway"
      "location" = "eastus2"
    }
    "eastus2-javascriptclient" = {
      "apsvc_name" = "javascriptclient"
      "location" = "eastus2"
    }
  },
]
```

And it is clearly a list, so it should qualify for `...` just fine.

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1**

Replacing locations with a compile time list works:

```
locals {
    locations = ["abc", "xyz"]
    x = merge(values({
        for location in local.locations: location => {
            for apsvc_name in var.apsvc_names: "${location}-${apsvc_name}" => {
                location = location
                apsvc_name = apsvc_name
            }
        }
    })...)
}
```

Which results in:

```
Outputs:

x = {
  "abc-backoffice" = {
    "apsvc_name" = "backoffice"
    "location" = "abc"
  }
  "abc-gateway" = {
    "apsvc_name" = "gateway"
    "location" = "abc"
  }
  "abc-javascriptclient" = {
    "apsvc_name" = "javascriptclient"
    "location" = "abc"
  }
  "xyz-backoffice" = {
    "apsvc_name" = "backoffice"
    "location" = "xyz"
  }
  "xyz-gateway" = {
    "apsvc_name" = "gateway"
    "location" = "xyz"
  }
  "xyz-javascriptclient" = {
    "apsvc_name" = "javascriptclient"
    "location" = "xyz"
  }
}
```

But replace "abc" with a variable value and it stops working:

```
locals {
    locations = [var.primary_location, "xyz"]
    x = merge(values({
        for location in local.locations: location => {
            for apsvc_name in var.apsvc_names: "${location}-${apsvc_name}" => {
                location = location
                apsvc_name = apsvc_name
            }
        }
    })...)
}
```

And bang:

```
Error: Invalid expanding argument value

  on ..\..\hosting-modules\web\app_hosting.tf line 5, in locals:
   5:     x = merge(values({
   6:         for location in local.locations: location => {
   7:             for apsvc_name in var.apsvc_names: "${location}-${apsvc_name}" => {
   8:                 location = location
   9:                 apsvc_name = apsvc_name
  10:             }
  11:         }
  12:     })...)
    |----------------
    | local.locations is tuple with 2 elements

The expanding argument (indicated by ...) must be of a tuple, list, or set
type.
```

**EDIT 2**

So, the code that should work (I improved it - `values` is not needed):

```
    merge([
        for location in local.locations: {
            for apsvc_name in var.apsvc_names: "${location}-${apsvc_name}" => {
                location = location
                apsvc_name = apsvc_name
            }
        }
    ]...)
```

does not work for mysterious reasons. I ended up with the following workaround:

```
    _y1 = [
        for location in local.locations: {
            for apsvc_name in var.apsvc_names: "${location}-${apsvc_name}" => {
                location = location
                apsvc_name = apsvc_name
            }
        }
    ]
    _y2 = flatten([for m in local._y1: [for k,v in m: { 
        key = k
        value = v
    }]])
    x = zipmap(local._y2.*.key, local._y2.*.value)
```

That one does work.

**EDIT 3**

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24033